# Showing a single TextView after clicks of 6 buttons in android

Tags: android, switch-statement

Hello everyone I am working on a random number generator app where I have implemented six buttons with a switch case that generates random numbers in android. Now trying to implement a logic where I want to show a retry button or text view after the user clicks all those six buttons. and also want to go to the first state after the user clicks the retry button. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.img_1:
            f2413X = false;
            Random random = new Random();
            int val = random.nextInt(100); // save random number in an integer variable
            textView3.setText(Integer.toString(val)); //convert to String and set it as text inside the textview
            box1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameScreen.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations")
                            .setMessage("You won " + val + " coins")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("COLLECT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int coins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(val))));

                                    prefs.setCoins(coins);
                                    displayCoins();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }, 200);
            break;
        case R.id.img_2:
            f2414Y = false;
            Random random2 = new Random();
            int val2 = random2.nextInt(100); // save random number in an integer variable
            textView4.setText(Integer.toString(val2)); //convert to String and set it as text inside the textview
            box2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameScreen.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations")
                            .setMessage("You won " + val2 + " coins")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("COLLECT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int coins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(val2))));

                                    prefs.setCoins(coins);
                                    displayCoins();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }, 200);
            break;
        case R.id.img_3:
            f2415Z = false;
            Random random3 = new Random();
            int val3 = random3.nextInt(100); // save random number in an integer variable
            textView5.setText(Integer.toString(val3)); //convert to String and set it as text inside the textview
            box3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler3 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameScreen.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations")
                            .setMessage("You won " + val3 + " coins")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("COLLECT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int coins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(val3))));

                                    prefs.setCoins(coins);
                                    displayCoins();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }, 200);
            break;
        case R.id.img_4:
            f2416a0 = false;
            Random random4 = new Random();
            int val4 = random4.nextInt(100); // save random number in an integer variable
            textView7.setText(Integer.toString(val4)); //convert to String and set it as text inside the textview
            box4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler4 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler4.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameScreen.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations")
                            .setMessage("You won " + val4 + " coins")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("COLLECT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int coins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(val4))));

                                    prefs.setCoins(coins);
                                    displayCoins();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }, 200);
            break;
        case R.id.img_5:
            f2417b0 = false;
            Random random5 = new Random();
            int val5 = random5.nextInt(100); // save random number in an integer variable
            textView8.setText(Integer.toString(val5)); //convert to String and set it as text inside the textview
            box5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler5 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler5.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameScreen.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations")
                            .setMessage("You won " + val5 + " coins")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("COLLECT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int coins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(val5))));

                                    prefs.setCoins(coins);
                                    displayCoins();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }, 200);
            break;
        case R.id.img_6:
            f2418c0 = false;
            GameScreen gameScreen2 = GameScreen.this;
            GameScreen.coinCollected(gameScreen2, gameScreen2.f2410U);
            Random random6 = new Random();
            int val6 = random6.nextInt(100); // save random number in an integer variable
            textView9.setText(Integer.toString(val6)); //convert to String and set it as text inside the textview
            box6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler6 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler6.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameScreen.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations")
                            .setMessage("You won " + val6 + " coins")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("COLLECT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    int coins = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(val6))));

                                    prefs.setCoins(coins);
                                    displayCoins();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }, 200);
            break;
        default:
            
            break;
    }
}
```

**and my Layout for this**

```
[![I want to show retry button or text view in the below circle][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: use sharedPref for this if click on first button set some value in preferences by clicking all button once clear the editor.

Comment: thank you for your time I really appreciate it. can you please go lil bit into detail or maybe write down the logic so I can better understand

Comment: if button1 click set Boolean value true to shared pref ie(prefs.setButtonState("Button1",true); after last button click check all the six button state   if all button state is true print "Retry" and clear all button state to false.

Comment: and also while setting state to true also disable the button and viceversa.

Comment: I got the idea you are talking about but as a new android developer can you please make this simple if you answer my query with an exapmle it will be great.

Comment: it worked. was little bit tricky but I figured it out thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList to maintain button states, then check in ArrayList whether all buttons are clicked and then display retry in TextView.

Comment: can you please go with an example